# Why i cannot see a View Based Application in my Project Assistant window in XCode

Tags: iphone

I have just installed XCode 3.1.4. I cannot see the ViewBased Application template when i try to create a View Based application for the iPhone. In fact i cannot see an iPhoneOS there at all. All i can see is Mac OS X. 
Do i have to install iPhone OS separately? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to sign up for a developer account and download the iOS SDK from http://developer.apple.com/ios

Comment: I have a developer account on http://developer.apple.com. Do i have to download iOS SDK separately?  Why? Wonder if it would work on Mac 10.5.8?

Comment: The iOS SDK includes the latest version of Xcode, the iOS Simulator, and of course all of the appropriate frameworks. You can install Xcode without the iOS SDK, like you did, if you only want to develop apps for Mac OS X. However, the latest SDK only works on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard. In order to use the latest SDK and submit iOS apps to the App Store you need a Mac running the latest version of Mac OS X.

Comment: Ok. I want to develop iPhone apps on my current MAC OS i.e. 10.5.8. What iOS SDK version do i need to install? Can you provide me the link please? Thanks

Comment: This version of the iOS SDK hasn't been available since Snow Leopard was released over a year ago. Apple no longer provides old versions of the SDK. I'm sure you can find an outdated version somewhere on the internet, but to submit apps to the App Store your app must be built against the iOS 4 SDK, which requires Snow Leopard. No questions asked.

Comment: So the bottom line is i need to upgrade my Mac OS to 10.6 and only then i can download iOS 4.1. Right? Wonder if there are any 3rd party websites available that can provide me with older versions of iOS for my Mac 10.5.8. Thank you

Comment: Correct, Snow Leopard is only $29 and it will be well worth it.